# Marshalling array of struct from C# to VC++

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to marshal an array of structs from C# to VC++.

The C++ function looks like this:

```
void myFunc(tFileListEntry* fileList);
```

And `tFileListEntry` is defined as:

```
typedef struct FILE_LIST
{
    uint16_t FileGroupCounter;
    uint32_t FileID;
    uint16_t NumbSamples;
} tFileListEntry;
```

In C# I declared the function like this:

```
[DllImport("MyLib", EntryPoint = "myFunc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void myFunc( [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] tFileListEntry[] fileList);
```

And `tFileListEntry` is defined as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class tFileListEntry
{
    public tFileListEntry(UInt16 fileGroupCounter, UInt32 fileId, UInt16 numbSamples)
    {
        FileGroupCounter = fileGroupCounter;
        FileID = fileId;
        NumbSamples = numbSamples;
    }

    public UInt16 FileGroupCounter;
    public UInt32 FileID;
    public UInt16 NumbSamples;
}
```

I can set a breakpoint in the C# code as well as in the C++ library. On the managed side the values look right, but on the unmanaged side I get only garbage.

I verified with `Marshal.SizeOf()` (in C#) and `sizeof()` (in C++) that the size of the struct is 12 bytes on both sides, so I don't think that padding/packing is an issue here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here is that on the C# side you have declared it as a class, not as a struct.

That means when you create the array on the C# side, each element of the array is a reference (4 or 8  bytes depending on the archtecture) not a struct (12 bytes), with the results you are seeing.

Try changing the C# class to struct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was that I defined `tFileListEntry` as `class` on the C# side. When I change it to `struct`, everything works fine.

Interestingly, I have another C++ function in the same library which accepts a single `struct` (not an array) and I can successfully marshal a C# `class` (with `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)`).